# Passing parameters from android to .net web service

Tags: .net, android, web-services, ksoap2

Im using ksoap2 to call web .net services. The call works just fine except when I pass paramaters. The passed paramaters are always recieved as null values by the web service. I dont know what the problem is, I hope someone can help.
Thanks,

Comment: What type of .NET Web service is it? Can you look at the WSDL for the service?

Comment: Are the parameters complex types?

Comment: I found the solution for the problem. It is more complicated than setting few options. If you guys are intersted in knowing the answer I will post it. 
Thanks all for your great suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Comment code **envelope.dotNet = true;**. This should do the trick

Comment: Ya I tried the option. Actually I inspected the source code in the library and this option basically is faked! it does nothing at all!